# Flex mobile LabelItemRenderer wordwrap?

Tags: apache-flex, mobile, flex-mobile

How can I set up the LabelItemRenderer or use any other item renderer that wouldn't truncate the overflowing text but would word wrap it?

**UPDATE:**

This blog post solved it:

http://flexponential.com/2011/08/21/adding-multiline-text-support-to-labelitemrenderer/

Comment: Have you tried setting `maxDisplayedLines` to something greater than 1?

Comment: It would be great if this property existed, but it doesn't. Not in LabeItemRenderer at least.

Answer (score 0):

What version of the SDK are you using?  You can just make a custom renderer and use a label in it and it'll work, use ItemRenderer as the base class

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:ItemRenderer width="100%"
                xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009"
                xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark">
        <s:Label text="{data}"
                 width="100%"/>
</s:ItemRenderer>
```